# React Native StackNavigator Title Change Causes Recursion

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I've split out the `navigationOptions` to the top of each screen to make things easy to understand, rather than keeping it in the TabNavigator. Here's an example of one screen:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  const {params = {}} = navigation.state;
  return {
    title: params.title != undefined ? `${params.title}` : "Step 1: Select a Letter",
    tabBarOnPress: ({...props, scene})=>{
      params.onFocus();
    },
    titleStyle: {
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  }  
};
```

Once a user selects a letter on this screen, I switch the view to show a different component (a list of items that start with that letter, for example).

I'd like to change the title of the TabNavigator Header to now show something like "Step 2: Select an item from the list". I saw on a [thread](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1746) that you can call a method from the method that rebuilds the view like this:

```
_letterSelectedHandler = (letter) => {
  this._changeTitle("Step 2: Select an item...");
  ...
}
```

With the method:

```
_changeTitle = (title) => {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({title});
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems to create an infinite loop. Is there a better way of simply changing the TabNavigator Header Title?

I should mention that I'm not using Redux or anything too complex, since I'm new to React Native. Please let me know if I can provide any more information to help illustrate the issue I'm having.

Comment: Instead of re-rendering the same component, I suggest nesting a stackNavigator at this TabNavigator route to go through the steps

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Any chance you have a link to a tutorial to do this? I'm new to RN.

Comment: Here's one, you should be able to google some more examples if need but basically instead of passing a component as the screen you just pass another navigator: https://codeburst.io/react-native-navigation-stack-navigator-inside-tab-navigator-inside-drawer-navigator-b2f21836708d